# How to make use of WITH in PostgreSQL to reduce query cost

Tags: postgresql-9.4, cte

I am trying to get twitter data of narendramodi using below command.

```
SELECT b.t_id,a.profile_image,b.tweet_text,e.media_media_url,b.retweet_count,b.favorite_count as like_count,count(reply_to_status_id) as reply_count,f.imp_count,f.eng_count,f.eng_rate 
FROM twitter_users a 
LEFT JOIN twitter_tweets b on a.user_id=b.user_id 
LEFT JOIN replies c on b.t_id = c.t_id 
LEFT JOIN media e on b.t_id = e.t_id 
LEFT JOIN twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates f 
    ON f.metric_timestamp=(select max(metric_timestamp) 
                           FROM twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates g 
                           WHERE g.t_id=f.t_id and g.t_id=b.t_id) 
WHERE a.twitter_screen_name= 'narendramodi' 
GROUP BY  b.t_id,a.profile_image 
,b.tweet_text,b.retweet_count,b.favorite_count,
e.media_media_url,f.imp_count,f.eng_count,f.eng_rate);
```

Query was working correctly But, in the above query I have used sub-select to get recent data of imp_counts of each tweet based on timestamp. Because of this sub-select Query_cost was huge and so it was taking more than 15min for query execution. I want to reduce that and should able to execute within 10seconds. For that reason I was trying to use WITH (CTE) expression

```
WITH metric_counts AS (
SELECT max(metric_timestamp),f.t_id,f.imp_count,f.eng_count,f.eng_rate 
FROM twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates f LEFT JOIN tweets b on 
f.t_id=b.t_id 
)
SELECT 
b.t_id,a.profile_image,b.tweet_text,e.media_media_url,b.retweet_count
,b.favorite_count as like_count, count(reply_to_status_id) as 
reply_count,metric_counts.imp_count
,metric_counts.eng_count,metric_counts.eng_rate 
FROM twitter_users as a 
LEFT JOIN tweets as b on a.twitter_user_id=b.twitter_user_id 
LEFT JOIN replies c on b.t_id = c.t_id 
LEFT JOIN media e on b.t_id = e.t_id 
LEFT JOIN metric_counts on metric_counts.t_id = b.t_id 
WHERE lower(a.twitter_screen_name)=lower('narendramodi') 
GROUP BY b.t_id,a.profile_image,b.tweet_text,e.media_media_url,
         b.retweet_count,b.favorite_count, 
         metric_counts.imp_count,metric_counts.eng_count,
         metric_counts.eng_rate;
```

The above WITH expression was giving results of imp_counts also for each tweet but not giving latest record/value. Can anyone help me in achieving this.

Here is the Query cost of WITH query

```
HashAggregate  (cost=1734856.13..1735618.48 rows=76235 width=673)
```

So can anyone help me to reduce cost to even lesser but giving results within 15 sec.

Query_cost

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=4923196.15..4923958.50 rows=76235 width=673) (actual time=51871.524..51872.333 rows=1513 loops=1)
   Group Key: imp_counts.tweet_status_id, a.profile_image, b.tweet_text, b.tweet_created_at, d.sentiment, d.emotion, b.retweet_count, b.favorit
e_count, e.media_media_url, imp_counts.tweet_impression_count, imp_counts.tweet_engagement_count, imp_counts.tweet_engagement_rate
   CTE imp_counts
     ->  Seq Scan on twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates f  (cost=0.00..3356389.12 rows=17676 width=47) (actual time=37516.805..41642.354 rows=6069
9 loops=1)
           Filter: (metric_timestamp = (SubPlan 2))
           Rows Removed by Filter: 3475596
           SubPlan 2
             ->  Result  (cost=0.90..0.91 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=3536295)
                   InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                     ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..0.90 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=3536295)
                           ->  Index Only Scan Backward using pk_twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates on twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates g  (cost=0.
56..55.57 rows=158 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=3536295)
                                 Index Cond: ((tweet_status_id = (f.tweet_status_id)::text) AND (metric_timestamp IS NOT NULL))
                                 Heap Fetches: 3536295
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1202381.45..1564329.39 rows=76235 width=673) (actual time=50478.887..51854.010 rows=10672 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1202380.90..1472231.15 rows=76235 width=641) (actual time=50478.871..51781.010 rows=10649 loops=1)
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1202380.34..1362479.87 rows=76235 width=626) (actual time=50478.841..51702.556 rows=10649 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: ((c.tweet_status_id)::text = (b.tweet_status_id)::text)
                     ->  Seq Scan on twitter_tweet_replies c  (cost=0.00..150216.68 rows=2606068 width=38) (actual time=0.041..692.358 rows=260
6068 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=1201427.40..1201427.40 rows=76235 width=607) (actual time=50477.837..50477.837 rows=1499 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1497kB
                           ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1200957.10..1201427.40 rows=76235 width=607) (actual time=50446.646..50476.746 rows=1499 
loops=1)
                                 Merge Cond: ((b.tweet_status_id)::text = (imp_counts.tweet_status_id)::text)
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=1199356.58..1199547.17 rows=76235 width=293) (actual time=8608.183..8608.530 rows=1499 loops=1
)
                                       Sort Key: b.tweet_status_id
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 597kB
                                       ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=29591.36..1193174.62 rows=76235 width=293) (actual time=3.714..8604.233 rows=
1499 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: ((b.twitter_user_id)::text = (a.twitter_user_id)::text)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on twitter_tweets b  (cost=0.00..1095151.30 rows=18045230 width=230) (actual time=0.0
26..5037.377 rows=18044981 loops=1)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=29214.36..29214.36 rows=30160 width=89) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 257kB
                                                   ->  Index Scan using twitter_screen_name_idx on twitter_users a  (cost=0.56..29214.36 rows=3
0160 width=89) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (lower((twitter_screen_name)::text) = 'narendramodi'::text)
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=1600.52..1644.71 rows=17676 width=314) (actual time=41838.456..41847.253 rows=60655 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: imp_counts.tweet_status_id
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 8540kB
                                       ->  CTE Scan on imp_counts  (cost=0.00..353.52 rows=17676 width=314) (actual time=37516.810..41684.563 r
ows=60699 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using tweet_sentiment_index on tweet_sentiment d  (cost=0.56..1.43 rows=1 width=34) (actual time=0.006..0.007 row
s=0 loops=10649)
                     Index Cond: ((b.tweet_status_id)::text = (tweet_status_id)::text)
         ->  Index Only Scan using twitter_tweet_media_pkey on twitter_tweet_media e  (cost=0.55..1.20 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.006..0.0
06 rows=0 loops=10649)
               Index Cond: (tweet_status_id = (b.tweet_status_id)::text)
               Heap Fetches: 1074
 Planning time: 2.913 ms
 Execution time: 51875.165 ms
(43 rows)
```

Comment: I have added query cost please check it once.

Comment: Please post the explain output in text, not image. Or paste the text to https://explain.depesz.com/ and then add the link in the question

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of sequential table scans on large tables in that plan.

`(twitter_user_id)` should be an index on `tweets` and probably more likely should be `(twitter_user_id, t_id)`.

Similarly, `replies.t_id` should be indexed as well.

The query refers to `metric_aggregates` and the query plan refers to `twitter_tweet_metric_aggregates` so you're not showing us a coherent picture. In any event I think that whatever the table is named, it also needs an index on `t_id`.

Once you get rid of the sequential scans, either this query will become fast enough, or at that point someone will be able to offer better advice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By mistake it was metric_aggregates in the query I have modified that. coming to index I have created indexes on the columns that you have mentioned although its doing seq_scan only instead of index_scan.

Comment: You need to narrow your query down to the simplest case that exhibits a seq scan and then figure out what index it needs in order to perform efficiently. You don't want to be seeing things like `Rows Removed by Filter: 3475596`